# Wrong code generation while using "-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon" on gcc 4.3.3

Tags: gcc, disassembly

I am maintaining an project which build with gcc-4.3.3 and I find something strange. The compiler will generate wrong code when I use specified compile option.
Here is my test code which on a file named test.cpp, var1.m_mask will be set correctly but the var2.m_mask is not set correctly, still keeping default value.
`

```
struct TestStruct
{
public:
    TestStruct(void);
    ~TestStruct(void);
    inline void SetFloatValue(float value)
    {
        m_fValue = value;
        m_mask |= 1;
    }
private:
    unsigned long long  m_mask;     //8 bytes
    float               m_fValue;   //4 byts
    char reserved[128 - 8 - 4 + 1]; //If sizeof(reserved) <= 116, it is ok
};
extern void OtherFunc(  const TestStruct &st );
void Test()
{
    //First variable
    TestStruct var1;
    //set var1.m_mask and var1.m_fValue
    var1.SetFloatValue( 100.0f );
    //call some function in case that var1 would be optimized
    OtherFunc( var1 );

    //Second variable
    TestStruct var2;
    //Set var2.m_fValue and var2.m_mask !!!
    var2.SetFloatValue( 100.0f );
    //call some function in case that var2 would be optimized
    OtherFunc( var2 );
}
```

`
And then compile it with this: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -O2 -g -o Test.obj Test.cpp

And I check the disassembly: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump -d -C Test.obj > Test.asm

I have added some note on disassembly code, the wrong codes are generated on address 58 and 5c.
`

```
Test.obj:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <Test()>:
   0:   e92d41f0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, lr}
   4:   e24dde11    sub sp, sp, #272    ; sp = &var2
   8:   e28d8088    add r8, sp, #136    ; r8 = &var1
   c:   e3a06001    mov r6, #1  ; 0x1
  10:   e3a07000    mov r7, #0  ; 0x0
  14:   e1a00008    mov r0, r8  ; r0 = &var1
  18:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <TestStruct::TestStruct()>    ; construct var1
  1c:   e1cd28d8    ldrd    r2, [sp, #136]  ; load m_mask to r2, r3
  20:   e1a00008    mov r0, r8              ; r0 = &var1
  24:   e1835007    orr r5, r3, r7          ; calc m_mask high 4bytes in r5
  28:   e1824006    orr r4, r2, r6          ; calc m_mask low 4bytes in r4
  2c:   e3003000    movw    r3, #0          ; low 2bytes for 100.0f 
  30:   e1cd48f8    strd    r4, [sp, #136]  ; r4,r5 store to var1.m_mask ()
  34:   e34432c8    movt    r3, #17096      ; 0x42c8 , high 2bytes for 100.0f 
  38:   e58d3090    str r3, [sp, #144]      ; store 100.0f to var1.m_fValue
  3c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <OtherFunc(TestStruct const&)>
  40:   e1a0000d    mov r0, sp              ; r0 = &var2, sp = &var2
  44:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <TestStruct::TestStruct()>    ; construct var2
  48:   e1cd20d0    ldrd    r2, [sp]        ; load m_mask to r2, r3
  4c:   e28d0e11    add r0, sp, #272        ; r0 = &var2 + 272
  50:   e1835007    orr r5, r3, r7          ; calc m_mask high 4bytes in r5
  54:   e1824006    orr r4, r2, r6          ; calc m_mask low 4bytes in r4
  58:   e5304110    ldr r4, [r0, #-272]!    ; !!! error : ldr should be str , r4 store to var2.m_mask low 4bytes
  5c:   e5905004    ldr r5, [r0, #4]        ; !!! error : ldr should be str , r5 store to var2.m_mask high 4bytes
  60:   e1a0000d    mov r0, sp              ; r0 = &var2
  64:   e3003000    movw    r3, #0          ; low 2bytes for 100.0f 
  68:   e34432c8    movt    r3, #17096      ; 0x42c8 , high 2bytes for 100.0f 
  6c:   e58d3008    str r3, [sp, #8]        ; store 100.0f to var2.m_fValue
  70:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <OtherFunc(TestStruct const&)>
  74:   e1a0000d    mov r0, sp
  78:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <TestStruct::~TestStruct()>
  7c:   e1a00008    mov r0, r8
  80:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <TestStruct::~TestStruct()>
  84:   e28dde11    add sp, sp, #272    ; 0x110
  88:   e8bd81f0    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, pc}
  8c:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
  90:   e1a00008    mov r0, r8
  94:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <TestStruct::~TestStruct()>
  98:   e1a00004    mov r0, r4
  9c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <__cxa_end_cleanup>
  a0:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
  a4:   e1a0000d    mov r0, sp
  a8:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <TestStruct::~TestStruct()>
  ac:   eafffff7    b   90 <TestStruct::~TestStruct()+0x90>
```

`
But when I change -O2 to -O1, the issue is gone.
When I remove one of "-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon", and still compile with -O2, the issue is gone too.
I have on idea why this would happen, could someone help me out? Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried with a more recent compiler?  It could be a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: [Looks correct with gcc 4.5.4](https://godbolt.org/z/6xsKjbsb9)

Comment: It does look right with gcc-4.5.4, still have no idea about gcc-4.3.3

Comment: Just to narrow things down, have you also checked the assembly actually output by the compiler (`gcc -S ...`)?  Because another possibility is that the compiler emits the correct assembly, but the assembler emits the wrong machine code.

Comment: I did try g++ -S before, still generate ldr instead of str

Comment: You can investigate this by compiling your example with `-S -fdump-rtl-all-slim`: that will emit numbered dump files corresponding to intermediate code after each compiler pass. By inspecting them you can find which pass transforms the code incorrectly. But as Nate said, you'll likely find that this is just a bug in gcc-4.3.3 (the latest bugfix release for that branch was gcc-4.3.6: https://gcc.gnu.org/news.html).

Comment: I have compiled the test code with -S -fdump-rtl-all-slim and got 75 files, I checked the RTL and could not find out why. As you said, the latest bugfix release for that branch was gcc-4.3.6, I have searched the bug list between version 4.3.3 and 4.3.6, and I did not find the exact bug. Could you point out the related bug? Thank you.